# How to parse config files generated by libconfig in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, c, libconfig

A few applications use https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig to generate configuration files. I was wondering if there were any wrappers or libraries or any way in general that would `parse`/`write` this kind of configuration file from disk but using javascript.

My file in question looks something like:

```
devices: (
{
    name: "Mouse";
    dpi: 1200;
    buttons: (
        {
            cid: 0xc3;
            action = {
                type: "Click";
            }
        }
    )
}
);
```